# how to open a specific image in the android photo gallery ?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have an android imageView.

I have set an OnClickListener to pick an image from Photo Gallery to be its src.

I now want to change the OnClick open this specific image in the photo gallery.

how do I do this? how to open a specific image in the photo gallery ?

Answer (score 0):

You can query with particular photoID, from below code you got all image and it's id and from id you can find particular image.

```
final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    imagecursor = getActivity().managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    ids = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        ids[i] = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }
```

find adapter code and set it in gridview from

[get full photogallery code](http://iandroiddeveloperphotogallery.blogspot.in/)